# How do movz instructions work on x86-64 architecture?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Are the instructions movzbl (%rdi), %eax and movzbq (%rdi), %rax equivalent? in x86-64 archiecture?

Shouldn't  movzbl (%rdi), %eax only zero extend upto the lower 32 bits of the %rax register while the other instruction zero extends the entire %register?

Comment: Writing to the full 32-bit `eax` always zero-extends into the 64-bit `rax`.